# Mac App just showing grey screen for Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: xcode, macos

I've just published a new Mac App and it is working correctly on my MacBook which is running OS X 10.8.2. However, I've been getting emails from people saying they only see a blank grey screen when the app launches. All these users are running OS X 10.7.5.

Is there a known issue that would cause something like this. I can't really go into specifics as I don't have a clue what could be causing this to happen or where the problem is.

Thanks

Comment: Install Lion in a new partition on your MBP, install Xcode and debug the problem yourself.  No one can answer this question without much more information and you don't seem to know even roughly where the problem lies.  Developing for 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8 is a pain in the ar$e.